# Is "unsigned" in cryptography's term the same with "unsigned" in programmer's term?

Tags: cryptography

I've been reading about cryptography for quite a while now, but it still bother me the term "unsigned" and "signed". I always think "unsigned" would mean integer data with no negative representation, but in cryptography they use "unsigned" and "signed" with almost anything. Can anyone clarify out this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cryptography "signed" can also mean "has a [digital signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature)". Unsigned would then be "doesn't have a digital signature".

Comment: And, to explain a bit further, this normally means: data is authenticated and integrity protected, or, of course, not authenticated or integrity protected.